# Query nested array of objects in node mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I am new to node + Mongo. I have data in following structure in mongoDB:

```
     var data = [{
    id:1,
    createdBy:"test",
    sharedTo:["john","shekar"]
    },
    {
    id:2,
    createdBy:"steve",
    sharedTo:["test","shekar"]
    },
{
    id:3,
    createdBy:"mark",
    sharedTo:["steve","test"]
    },
{
    id:4,
    createdBy:"akuni",
    sharedTo:["john","shekar","mark"]
    },
{
    id:5,
    createdBy:"test",
    sharedTo:["mark","shekar"]
    },
{
    id:6,
    createdBy:"mark",
    sharedTo:["test","akuni"]
    }]
```

I want to query this to get all the records created by the user "test" and those records shared to "test". How can I do that?

Expected Result:

```
[{
    id:1,
    createdBy:"test",
    sharedTo:["john","shekar"]
    },

{
    id:5,
    createdBy:"test",
    sharedTo:["mark","shekar"]
    },
{
    id:6,
    createdBy:"mark",
    sharedTo:["test","akuni"]
    }]
```

I Have tried Something like

```
var user = "test";
    data.find({createdBy:user,sharedTo:{$elemMatch:[user]}},function(err, resp){

    });
```

but it is returning empty

Comment: What query have you actually tried? People are generally happy to *help* when it's clear you have made some effort, but there is no query attempt in the question. Also there really is no "nested array" component here at all. I honestly suggest reading [Query Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/) in the core documentation since you don't appear familiar with the basics of MongoDB queries. This will help you and alleviate the need to post a question for every new thing you come across. MongoDB really does not care that your string is in an array.

Comment: If the linked answer and documentation are not directly clear enough, then this is basically solved by `.find({ "$or": [{ "createdBy": "test" }, { "sharedTo": "test" }] })`

Comment: You should take a look at `$elemMatch` operator as well.

Comment: @Dijkstra You really should not. This has nothing to do with `$elemMatch`. I suggest you take at look at [Specify Multiple Conditions for Array of Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#specify-multiple-conditions-for-array-of-documents) in the core documentation in order so that you too can actually understand when and why `$elemMatch` is used. This is **not** one of those cases.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thank you for the suggestion. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mongodb's [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) query operator

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    { createdBy: "test" },
    { sharedTo: "test" }
  ]
})
```